# Dynamically resize TableViewCell with and with out images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using swift3, I want to allow users to create posts of either pictures or simple text posts. I have everything working fine except for when I create a post of just text, the UIImageView in the cell fills out space in the TableViewCell. Ideally, if the user creates a post of just text, the TableViewCell will only include everything down to the caption label but not the UIImageView (see image). How can I go about this.

**Research:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWO9rldyUE,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEMUOaamcDA, https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

**Current Code**

```
    func configureCell(post: Post){
    self.post = post
    likesRef = FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_REF.child("likes").child(post.postID)
    userRef = FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.child(post.userID).child("profile")

    self.captionText.text = post.caption
    self.likesLbl.text = "\(post.likes)"

    self.endDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(post.time))

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        self.currentUser = MainUser(uid: post.userID, userData: snap!)
        self.userNameLbl.text = self.currentUser.username
        if let profileImg = self.currentUser.profileImage {
            self.profileImg.loadImageUsingCache(urlString: profileImg)
        } else {
            self.profileImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "requests_icon")
        }
    })

    // This is where I belive I need to determine wether or not the cell should have an image or not.
        if let postImg = post.imageUrl {
            self.postImg.loadImageUsingCache(urlString: postImg)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using storyboard to create your UI, in that case you can add a height constraint to your `UIImageView` (make sure to connect it your cell in order to use it in code) and change the constraint and the height of your tableview when required.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var postImageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
}


class ViewController: UITableViewController {

     var dataSource: [Model] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //Cell without image
        if dataSource[indexPath.row].image == nil {
            return 200
        }
        //Cell with image
        return 350
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        //Adjust the height constraint of the imageview within your cell
        if dataSource[indexPath.row].image == nil {
            cell.postImageHeight.constant == 0
        }else{
            cell.postImageHeight.constant == 150
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```